# Broken terminal, terminator and apt

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, apt, python, gnome-terminator

I have an Ubuntu 18.LTS and accidentally triggered

update-alternatives --config python3.6

That seems to have broken my system since now neither terminal, terminator and apt seems to be not working

Terminator

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 23, in <module>
    import psutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
```

Terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

apt

Trying for instance to add repository (just trying to install 3.5 as it seems to be the default used for all this programs)

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'softwareproperties'
```

Now, I must say I have different versions of Python that I have installed with pyenv:

```
 ✘ internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.13
* 3.8.3 (set by /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/version)
  3.9-dev
```

Most of those are installed in /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/versions

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -ltra /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/versions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  6 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 jun 13  2020 3.9-dev
drwxr-xr-x  6 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 jun 16  2020 3.8.3
drwxrwxr-x 13 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 sep 27 20:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb  9 01:05 2.7.13
drwxr-xr-x  5 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb  9 02:12 .
```

Now if I check /usr/bin/python I see the following

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -ltra /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 mar 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 mar 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     152 abr  9  2020 /usr/bin/python3-pbr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 jul 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5486352 jul 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3629032 ago  4  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 feb  8 23:49 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 feb  9 00:50 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

Seems I don't have a Python 3.5 which "I think" is what terminator uses...

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  cat /usr/bin/terminator 
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

And my python3 resolves to actually the same as my python...

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jun 16 2020, 18:30:59) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  python3
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jun 16 2020, 18:30:59) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If I try to update-alternatives again, I get this message...

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/local/bin/python3.7
Nothing to configure.
```

Not even sure why it mentions python3.7 there? I do see though several pythons in /usr/local/bin

```
✘ internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -ltra /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 dic 24  2018 /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config -> python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14925232 dic 24  2018 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14925232 dic 24  2018 /usr/local/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3097 dic 24  2018 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14642520 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3.5m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14642520 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3071 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3.5-config -> python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 feb  9 00:46 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> python3.5-config
```

On top of this lsb_release does not work either!

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  lsb_release -a                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

Don't even know how many other stuff is broken...any suggestions on getting back to normal that don't imply having to re-install Ubuntu?

Thanks!

**UPDATE BASED ON RESPONSE FROM @Stewart**

I'm using Xterm to get output I'm posting here. By the way I'm on 18.04, not 20.04

So going back to your suggestions

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  file $(which terminator) $(which xterm) $(which gnome-terminal)
/usr/bin/terminator:     symbolic link to ../share/terminator/terminator
/usr/bin/xterm:          ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=abd5692fa8891e01f24e8ae7f40f218662f098d9, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

So looks like my gnome-terminal is Python based too?

```
internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  file $(which add-apt-repository) $(which apt) $(which apt-cache) $(which dpkg)
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository: Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/bin/apt:                ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=c460d1db846110f4ae24cb54b4cfee967d022c09, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/usr/bin/apt-cache:          ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=2e75b0850b2936259281b093ecf906bf70a1d7b8, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/usr/bin/dpkg:               ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=978cfb3eb2e5cee720ae1c551c12595f1aa211f5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Checking apt and the like:

```
internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  file $(which add-apt-repository) $(which apt) $(which apt-cache) $(which dpkg)
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository: Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/bin/apt:                ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=c460d1db846110f4ae24cb54b4cfee967d022c09, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/usr/bin/apt-cache:          ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=2e75b0850b2936259281b093ecf906bf70a1d7b8, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/usr/bin/dpkg:               ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=978cfb3eb2e5cee720ae1c551c12595f1aa211f5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Now when I try to check Python 3

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -go $(which python3)  
-rwxrwxr-x 1 424 jun 13  2020 /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

So it looks like this pointing to some python installed by pyenv

Comment: Bingo! You found the problem!  `pyenv`'s python3 is interferring with your distribution's python3.  The solution is either to uninstall pyenv or to fix pyenv,  Unfortunately, I can't help you further as pyenv isn't in Debian's archive.  I would offer the advice that a single package management tool is usually enough. Debian packages are made (and tested) to work with other Debian packages, so using third party tools (even `pip`) is rarely optimal.

Comment: @Stewart I'd like to keep pyenv but I don't mind uninstalling it if it fixes the issue. Even if I uninstall it...how do I get back my system-wide python up & running?

Comment: It may be as simple as removing `~/.pyenv/shims/` from `$PATH`.  Do that and check `which python3` again.  Otherwise, the `apt reinstall` steps could be necessary.

Comment: Actually, if you log in as a different (new?) user, you shouldn't have access to that `pyenv` installation.  That's a good way to see if it's your machine or just your user which is broken.  If it's just the user, then you should never need any commands requiring `sudo` to solve it.

Comment: @Stewart I tried but after rebooting I was getting no keyboard or mouse on login...I just reinstalled Ubuntu..thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest using a terminal which is not dependent on python.  `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` would work:

```
$ file $(which terminator) $(which xterm) $(which gnome-terminal)
/usr/bin/terminator:     Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/bin/xterm:          ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ...
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ...
```

While `add-apt-repository` may be a python script, `apt`, and `dpkg` are not and should still work for you:

```
$ file $(which add-apt-repository) $(which apt) $(which apt-cache) $(which dpkg)
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository: Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/bin/apt:                ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-...
/usr/bin/apt-cache:          ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-...
/usr/bin/dpkg:               ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-
```

You can use `apt` to re-install / reconfigure the broken package including some broken links.  I'm on Debian Testing, but the core python packages for Debian and Ubuntu are maintained by the same person, so I suspect it's similar for you. Here I'm looking for the relevant packages:

```
$ ls -go $(which python3) 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 9 Dec 23 07:05 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9

$ dpkg -S $(which python3) $(which python3.9)
python3-minimal: /usr/bin/python3
python3.9-minimal: /usr/bin/python3.9

$ apt-cache show python3 | grep Depends:
Depends: python3.9 (>= 3.9.1-1~), ...
Pre-Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.9.1-1)

$ apt-cache show python3.9 | grep Depends:
Depends: python3.9-minimal (= 3.9.1-4)...
```

Now we know which packages handle this link and the binaries associated with it.  In your case, you are on Ubuntu 20.04, so you'll want `python3.8` instead of `python3.9`.

I would try to fix it with:

```
sudo apt reinstall python3 python3-minimal python3.8 python3.8-minimal
```

What's special about this is that it re-invokes the scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.{pre,post}{inst,rm}` which are responsible for performing any byte-compilation, and using `update-alternatives` (when appropriate).

If this doesn't work, I'd take a look at the output of `update-alternatives --config python3`.  On Debian testing I get:

```
$ update-alternatives --config python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

If you get the same thing, it means alternatives no longer manage python3.  I'm not sure when this changed, if you don't get this it's probably why there's a problem on your machine.  When an old python3 version was removed, the `prerm` responsible for `update-alternatives --remove python3` was never run.  Try running `update-alternatives --config python3` and check what options are available.  If you have `python3.8` as an option, and it's the highest priority, then rerun this as `sudo` and select `auto`.

```
$ update-alternatives --config python3
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.8      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.5      1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8      1111      manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.7      1081      manual mode
```

However, I suspect `python3.8` is not in your list and this is why you are having problems.  Even with Debian buster (released in 2018), we had python3.7 so python3.5 is pretty old.  Since `python3` packages now manage links on their own, when you ran `update-alternatives --config python3` you probably replaced the good link with something that's out of date.  In this case, I'd manually remove the python3 alternative with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3
```

Then re-install the python packages again.

Whenever a new `python3` is released, there is some time spent running tests on all dependent packages in the archive.  If a package fails, then bug reports are filed and maintainers do what they can to ensure their package works with the latest version of `python3`.  You don't normally need to have multiple point-releases installed.  `terminator` should work fine with the latest `python3`.  I suspect it would have otherwise been removed from the archive if it failed the transition and never released with Ubuntu 20.04.  The exception to this are PPAs (or any 3rd party repository), which are beyond the reach of the official distributions and could have anything in them including a version of `terminator` which only works with `python3.5`.

Comment: Hello @Stewart,

Comment: Hello @Stewart,

I think the problem is with pyenv...if I run this

 ls -go $(which python3) 

I see the following

-rwxrwxr-x 1 424 jun 13  2020 /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/shims/python3

running pyenv global, seems it's managed by pyenv now

 ✘ internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  pyenv global
3.8.3
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.13
* 3.8.3 (set by /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/version)
  3.9-dev

Comment: Gosh will edit my answer...this comments is useless

Comment: please check my updated response, not sure how to proceed since it seems my python3 alias is pointing to a python installed by pyenv