# How to prevent changing default Python version?

Tags: debian, python, defaults

Many applications I use (`arandr`, `inkscape`, ...) get broken when default Python version is set to Python-3 by `update-alternatives --config python`.

How can I prevent myself from setting default Python version to Python-3 in the future, like we do for `/etc/resolv.conf` by `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using? The Python packages in Debian don’t use alternatives, so the fact that you have a `python` alternative suggests that you’ve already messed up your installation, before even getting as far as `update-alternatives --config python` and choosing `python3`.

Comment: Weird, I found that python isn't using `update-alternatives` anymore when I answered a similar question earlier this week.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633550/272848

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm using Debian Buster. I remember that I intentionally registered the Python versions some time ago, while chasing some kind of issue.

Comment: @Stewart in Debian, the Python packages stopped using alternatives in 2001 IIRC. The change is more recent in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ceremcem oh I’ve no doubt it was intentional and with the best of intentions. My point is that you’re asking for help protecting yourself from a sub-optimal setup in the first place; it would be better IMO to revert to the standard setup instead, but explaining how to do that would require knowing what you did.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm nearly sure that if I remove the Python alternatives and revert to standard Debian setup, I may forget all about this (I may not, I don't know) and I restart whole story all over again (register Python alternatives, select Python-3 as default). Is there anything wrong to set Python-3 path to `/somewhere/non/exists`? Or should I create a wrapper script in `/usr/bin/update-alternatives` which will basically perform a MITM in case of `--config python` switch is given?

Comment: @ceremcem it sounds like you don’t trust yourself to administer your system ;-). There’s no 100% sysadmin-proof protection; if you’re OK with changing things in `/usr`, you’ll always find a way around whatever you’ve set up. Perhaps a read-only root or `/usr` would help. But the basic rule to follow is that `/usr` is off-limits (apart from `/usr/local`), you should never change anything in there manually.

Comment: Yeah, that might sound like that too :) Actually it should be interpreted as "creating constraints", like a CAD software does. Or maybe it should be interpreted as pre/post commit Git hooks which simply displays a warning message on a specific case.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I prevent myself from setting default Python version to Python-3 in the future

Remove python versions from `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
```

In the future the following command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

will show you:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

Comment: That won't make me stop, because if I'm instructed to "set the Python version to Python-3" I'll re-register the Python versions (as currently registered Python versions are registered by me, some time ago, while chasing a problem). Can I safely register the path of Python3 version to something like "`/do/not/select/this`"?